# Enviar array por ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Resumen**

Estoy usando un mutiselect de harvesthq.

Cuando selecciono múltiples opciones y lo mando por ajax a una pagina de .php solo me inserta una opción cuando se supone que estoy mandando un string separando por comas.

**HTML**

```
<select data-placeholder="Seleccione uno o varios" multiple class="chosen-select " name="SelectMultiple[]"  id="SelectMultiple">
                        <option disabled selected value="" required>Seleccione uno o varios</option>
                        <option value="1" required>1</option>
                        <option value="3" required>2</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

De esta manera estoy residiendo los valores que selecciono y luego lo convierto en un string
y luego lo mando a la pagina php.

```
function ValidValues() {
   var cadena = $("#SelectMultiple").val();
   var Respuesta = cadena.toString();
  $.post("../Modelo/InsertRespuesta.php", {
            Respuesta :  Respuesta,
          },
            function (data, status) {
              loader.classList.remove("active");
            })
}
```

**PHP**

```
include ('Conexion.php');
$Respuesta =  $_REQUEST['Respuesta'];
$insert ="INSERT INTO `respuesta`(`Respuesta`) VALUES ('$Respuesta')";
$res= mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
```

**Problema**

Como había dicho en la parte superior,el problema esta en la inserción del string de las opciones que se selecciono separado por comas.

Ejem: Se selecciono 3 opciones = 1,2,3;

cuando inserta en la BD, solo parece "1" en como insertado.

Alguien sabe porque pasa ?

Comment: ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(Respuesta);` o un `alert(Respuesta);`
? Debes verificar lo que estás mandando en realidad.

Comment: Me muestra 1,2,3

Comment: Suena a que la longitud de la columna en la base de datos es menor a lo que esperas. Cuántos caracteres están especificados en esa columna? Dicho de otra manera, es `char` o `nvarchar`, o es `char(10)`, `nvarchar(max)`. Cuál es la longitud de la columna?

Comment: Si arriel, era ese error, tenia en mi BD como int(11) y debia de ser un varchar, muchas gracias !!!

hay alguna forma de darte algunos puntos  ?

Comment: Ojo clínico, @Arriel. Coloca tu comentario como respuesta.

Comment: Estaría encantado, pero no entiendo cómo MySQL hace la conversión implícita de `1,2,3` a `int(11)`, y por qué no lanza una excepción en lugar de únicamente insertar `1`. Si tú, @A.Cedano, tienes la respuesta, tu explicación sería más valiosa que la mía.